# Changing Container on button click in Sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have Two containers in my Sencha Architect Frame work 2.0.

The first container contains a login button.
So on the click i.e. tap event of that button i want that my view changes from container1 to container2.

How can this be done.

Thanks
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

On your button's `tap` event, you should run something like this:

`yourOuterContainer.animateActiveItem(1);`

note: here I assume that your outer container contains 2 components: First Container and Second Container (so your Second Container has index 1).

Comment: no....it is not like that..i have two different containers and i have to move between them.

Comment: please update some of your source code, or upload them to senchafiddle, or just describe your app a little bit more

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Make a Panel with layout: card, set set activeItem(0) for the panel
2. put the two container inside the panel, be sure, that the login container is first and the other second in order
3. in the tap event of the panel apply setActiveItem(1) for the panel

This way you switch between these two views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the navigation view component... Sencha Architect documentation provides a easy guide to implement this

http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/navigationview